# ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in Nexus Repo

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, nexus

I am getting the following exception. I'm using intellij 2017, Ultimate version, Nexus OSS version 3, Maven, & Spring Boot. In previous project I was using Gradle, it seemed to work well, but the moment I try tutorial-based Spring-Boot project in maven, then i'm stuck with such an exception. I am failing to understand why.

```
    sean@sean-PC:/dev_0/proj/idea/spring/spring-data-jpa/spring-core-spring-mvc$ mvn package -X
    Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T18:41:47+02:00)
    Maven home: /dev_0/app/mvn
    Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: /dev_0/app/jdk/jre
    Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "linux", version: "4.8.0-46-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
    [DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
    [DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
    [DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
    [DEBUG]   Imported: ** Other stuff {Deleted to prevent Clutter}**
    [DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
    [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
    [DEBUG] Reading global settings from /dev_0/app/mvn/conf/settings.xml
    [DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/sean/.m2/settings.xml
    [DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /dev_0/app/mvn/conf/toolchains.xml
    [DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /home/sean/.m2/toolchains.xml
    [DEBUG] Using local repository at /dev_0/repo
    [DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /dev_0/repo
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [DEBUG] Using mirror feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/) for master (http://localhost:8081/repository/master/).
    [DEBUG] Using mirror feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/) for hotfix (http://localhost:8081/repository/hotfix/).
    [DEBUG] Using mirror feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/) for release (http://localhost:8081/repository/release/).
    [DEBUG] Using mirror feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/) for develop (http://localhost:8081/repository/develop/).
    [DEBUG] Using mirror feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/) for feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/).
    [DEBUG] Using mirror feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/) for central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
    [DEBUG] Extension realms for project guru.springframework:springmvc:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
    [DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
    [DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.0.RELEASE: (none)
    [DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
    [DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:1.3.0.RELEASE: (none)
    [DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
    [DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
    [DEBUG] Project: guru.springframework:springmvc:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [DEBUG] Tasks:   [package]
    [DEBUG] Style:   Regular
    [DEBUG] =======================================================================
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building springmvc 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
    [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/
    [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/ with username=sean, password=***
    Downloading: http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
    [DEBUG] Writing tracking file /dev_0/repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom.lastUpdated
    [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 is missing, no dependency information available
    [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/
    [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/ with username=sean, password=***
    Downloading: http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.jar
    [DEBUG] Writing tracking file /dev_0/repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.jar.lastUpdated
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 0.342 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-09T08:27:50+02:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/292M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/) -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:128)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:179)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:284)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:155)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:131)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:109)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/)
            at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
            at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
            at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
            at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:124)
            ... 26 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 in feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/)
            at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)
            at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
            at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
            at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
            at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
            at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
            at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
            ... 30 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Here is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

                    <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springmvc</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <packaging>jar</packaging>

                    <name>springmvc</name>
                    <description>Demo project for Spring 
 Boot</description>

                    <!-- download artifacts from this repo -->
                    <repositories>
                            <repository>
                                    <id>feature</id>
                                    <name>Feature Plugin Repository</name>
                                    <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/</url>
                                    <releases>
                                            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                                    </releases>
                            </repository>
                    </repositories>

                    <pluginRepositories>
                            <pluginRepository>
                                    <id>feature</id>
                                    <name>Feature Plugin Repository</name>
                                    <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/</url>
                                    <layout>default</layout>
                                    <snapshots>
                                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                                    </snapshots>
                                    <releases>
                                            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                                    </releases>
                            </pluginRepository>
                    </pluginRepositories>


                    <parent>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
                            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
                    </parent>

                    <properties>
                            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                    </properties>

                    <dependencies>
                            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin -->
                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
                            </dependency>


                            <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools &ndash;&gt;-->

                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                            </dependency>

                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                            </dependency>

                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                            </dependency>

                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                            </dependency>

                            <!--WebJars-->
                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                                    <version>3.3.5</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.1.4</version>
                            </dependency>

                    <!--encryption lib-->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.2</version>
                    </dependency>


                    <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                                    <scope>test</scope>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
                            </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                    <build>
                            <plugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                    </build>
            </project>
```

& here is my settings.xml file:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<localRepository>/dev_0/repo</localRepository>



  <pluginGroups>

  </pluginGroups>


  <proxies>

  </proxies>


  <servers>

    <server>
      <id>feature</id>
      <username>sean</username>
      <password>****</password>
    </server>

    <server>
      <id>develop</id>
      <username>sean</username>
      <password>****</password>
    </server>

    <server>
      <id>hotfix</id>
      <username>sean</username>
      <password>*****</password>
    </server>

    <server>
      <id>release</id>
      <username>sean</username>
      <password>****</password>
    </server>

    <server>
      <id>master</id>
      <username>sean</username>
      <password>****</password>
    </server>

  </servers>


  <mirrors>

    <mirror>
      <id>feature</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>feature</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/</url>
    </mirror>

    <mirror>
      <id>develop</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
      <name>develop</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/develop/</url>
    </mirror>

    <mirror>
      <id>release</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
      <name>release</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/release/</url>
    </mirror>

    <mirror>
      <id>hotfix</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
      <name>hotfix</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/hotfix/</url>
    </mirror>

    <mirror>
      <id>master</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
      <name>master</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/master/</url>
    </mirror>

  </mirrors>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>feature</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>feature</id>
          <name>Feature Repo for feature-builds</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>develop</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>develop</id>
          <name>Develop Repo for develop-builds</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/develop/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>release</id>
          <name>Release Repo for release-builds</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/release/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
         <!-- <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots> -->
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>hotfix</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>hotfix</id>
          <name>Hotfix Repo for hotfix-builds</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/hotfix/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
         <!-- <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots> -->
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>master</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>master</id>
          <name>Master Repo for master-builds</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/master/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
         <!-- <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots> -->
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>feature</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>develop</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>release</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>hotfix</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>master</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

What am I missing?

Another stacktrace for another build attempt:

```
[INFO] Building springmvc 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Downloading: http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.0.RELEASE.pom
    [WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available
    Downloading: http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 0.336 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-09T08:49:39+02:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/292M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE in feature (http://localhost:8081/repository/feature/) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
```

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward. You have your maven configuration pointing at a repository in YOUR machine `http://localhost:8081` and your machine clearly doesn't have the artifact your project require which is `spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.RELEASE` What you fail to understand from the tutorial (and this is my guess) is that maven needs to communicate to a repository. If you installed this repository in your machine you didn't configure it properly so it can search online when it doesn't have a required dependency.

Comment: Hi @JorgeCampos, Thank you for your response. I have decided to change  to the Artifactory especially after performing an analysis of the repository managers: Artifactory versus Nexus. On this link 
[github io](https://binary-repositories-comparison.github.io/) and this link 
[jfrog](https://www.jfrog.com/blog/artifactory-vs-nexus-integration-matrix/)

Comment: Artifactory is a lot easier to setup, configure, & get it up & running. I didn't have any troubles setting up JFrog Artifactory. :-)

I've come to learn that Nexus only has approximately 8% of JFrog Artifactory features & support. Artifactory has a very good setup & configuration-manual. Hence my exception that I was experiencing are all gone... But Thank you soo much. :-)

Comment: That's great to hear. I know that you are now working in on an local environment. In a work place environment it would be great to have a local centralized server (intranet) with one of those repository servers set up. So everybody in the project can benefit from it. Keep that in mind. Cheers